# C# initialization and destruction of marshaled memory

Tags: c#, c, marshalling

I have a function from a C library that allocates memory for structures based on their size and id, the ids are assigned at runtime using a registrar function. The function looks like this

```
void *allocate_objects(uint32_t structure_id, uint32_t size, uint32_t count, 
                       void *(*constructor)(void *), void (*destructor)(void *));
```

In addition it takes a pointer to the constructor function used to initialize the allocated memory and a destructor that is called once the memory is deallocated (it may not be freed, but is no longer reserved and can be reused by the library).

The library does not care what is actually inside the memory allocated using `allocate_objects`, it only manages the memory for them.

I want to use it from my C# code with C# structs and classes, however I do not know how to correctly pass the constructors and destructors to the allocation function.

I have several ideas on how it could be done:

1. Use reflection to get constructors and destructors for the types from the factory functions that would then be passed to the C code
2. Have the classess/structs that are used with the library implement some member function (ex. `onCreate` and `onDestroy`) that would then be called from the factory functions

I am a noob at marshaling C# code so I have some questions regarding these ideas:

1. Is there some sort of a way to use reflection with already allocated memory?
2. If I use overloaded virtual functions, is it safe to call them on uninitialized memory (`allocate_objects` would preform an equivalent of `malloc` and the memory would not be zero'd)
3. What would be the constraints for the types I use with the library? I assume that I would not be allowed to use any non-primitive type as the GC would not be able to reach the memory used by the C library, or is there a way to force the GC when the object is being destroyed by the C library?

Comment: @HansPassant The program itself is not entirely C#, it uses C# for some parts of the code to ease scripting, however most performance oriented code is in C.

Comment: This function is used by other parts of the C code and it would make less sense and require more work to pass pointers to C# allocated objects to the library instead, as the rest of the C code expects the memory to be allocated and managed using this function